# 15.04 Upgrade on AMD

Tags: graphics, ati, 15.04

I have a AMD Radeon R4/R5; after 15.04 upgrades, I'm stuck at the purple screen with low-graphics complaint. So I boot into the recovery session of the same generic headers and run in failsafeX mode. Now it asks me if I want to do it because

```
Continuing will remount your  / fillesystem in read/write mode and mount any other filesystem defined in /ect/fstab. Do you wish to continue ?
```

at this moment i also have windows 8 running on dual boot mode (at fully shut down state). i'm wondering if it screws up my partitions. is there any better ways to solve this? i'm aware of doing

```
ctrl + alt + f1
```

but not sure whether my hard drive will be affected.